# How to run multi condition check in mongodb update query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following scenario. 
I need to check multiple condition in a single update query.

Sample Data :

```
"host" : "zigwheels.com",
"lastAccessDate" : "20140819",
"sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39"
```

Here is my requirement  :

```
obj=db.userFrequency.find({"host" : "xyz.com", "sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39"});
if(obj!=null){
   if(obj.get("lastAccessDate")!= todayDate){
     //If page has not visited today, increment count by 1 and update "lastAccessDate"=todayDate
     db.userFrequency.update({"host" : "xyz.com","sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39"},{$set : {"lastAccessDate"=todayDate},$inc : {"count":1}});
   }
   else{
      // If page visited today{lastAccessDate==todayDate}, no need to update count
   } 

}else{
    //Insert the new Entry  
    db.userFrequency.update({"host" : "xyz.com","sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39"},{$set : {"lastAccessDate"=todayDate},$inc : {"count":1}},{upsert:true});
}
```

I need to do the above operation in a single query but I have GB's of data.
I tried above like below :

```
db.userFrequency.update({"host" : "xyz.com","lastAccessDate"!=todayDate,"sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39"},{$set : {"lastAccessDate"=todayDate},$inc : {"count":1}});
```

but it inserts new entry because the above condition requires three checks.

Please suggest a solution for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's awkward if you store your date as a string. Store dates as date type fields and this is easy:

```
> db.userFrequency.insert({
    "host" : "zigwheels.com",
    "lastAccessDate" : ISODate("2014-08-19"),
    "sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39"
})
> var today = ISODate("2014-08-25")
> db.userFrequency.update({
    "host" : "zigwheels.com",
    "lastAccessDate" : { "$lt" : today },
    "sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39"
},
{
    $set : { "lastAccessDate" : today},
    $inc : { "count" : 1 }
})
> db.userFrequency.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53fbd08...398"),
    "host" : "zigwheels.com",
    "lastAccessDate" : ISODate("2014-08-25T00:00:00Z"),
    "sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39",
    "count" : 1
}
```

I used the `$lt` operator for the date test because users won't access the website from the future...hopefully. Using proper dates also surfaces another important issue- what timezone defines today? Right now, for me, it's tomorrow in Australia...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll use  date type fields to store date but It is not fulfilling the second "if condition" as i have described in the first post because if a user has visited today already,then its "lastAccessDate":todayDate.
So, when we comes to third condition,"lastAccessDate":{$lt : todayDate} , it fails and upsert the new entry.

Comment: If `lastAccessDate` in a document is today, then it is not `$lt` today, so the document will not match the update criteria and will not be updated. There is no `upsert : true` option set, so no new document will be inserted.

Comment: If don't set the upsert:true condition, then can we handle the entry for a new visitor(who is visiting page first time)

Comment: If you set `upsert : true`, it looks like everything would be fine. If there's no matching doc, it inserts a new one with the given `sessionId` and `host`, a `lastAccessedDate` of today, and a `count` of 1.

Comment: I tried a lot... could you please give me a working query,,, as i tried a lot and getting duplicate entries again and again.

Comment: Can you give an example of a document and the query that caused a duplicate?

Comment: db.userFrequency.update({ "host" : "zig.com" , "lastAccessDate" : { "$lt" : "20140828"} , "sessionId" : "ff8378ed-ccda-4a75-b24b-4a4bb1153e39"},{ "$set" : { "lastAccessDate" : "20140828"} , "$inc" : { "count" : 1}},{upsert:true})        --->> This is my sample query.This works fine if it is a new entry or "lastAccessDate"!=todayDate but if entry exists and "lastAccessDate"==todayDate, then ["lastAccessDate"!=todayDate] is evaluated to false and it will upsert new entry for same date.Please check it where i am wrong.

Comment: Make the `$lt` into a `$lte`.

Comment: I think you didnt get my scenario, using $lte it is incrementing the count for a user who have already visited today.But anyways i got the solution for my problem using "unique" index.Anyways thanks  for the advice.